# Python: Generate random letter then Keystroke said letter

Tags: python, random, numbers, keystroke, letter

(I am using Python under Mac OS)

Hey Guys,

i am looking for a way to random generate a letter (a-z) and then keystroke it.
The way I usually do keystrokes is:

cmd = """
osascript -e 'tell application 'System Events' to keystroke "insert_letter_here"'
"""

os.system(cmd)

This won't accept random.letter since it would keystroke the exact spelling of random.letter.

Does anyone know a way to first generate a random letter and then keystroke it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, but here is one:

```
import random, string, keyboard

random_letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
keyboard.write(random_letter)
```

The random letter can be both lower and upper case in this example because string.ascii_letters returns:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

(you may have to pip install the keyboard library)